# countifs odd behavior -- using "wild card" still results dont sum to total

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

We are using google sheets as our V1 linguistics database.
Each row represents a dataset, the columns represent various aspects of each dataset.
Hours of audio, dialects, topics, acoustics issues, etc.

I thought making a tab with a countifs() that points to cells with validation would be simple way to make the database accessible to others.

However I get this strange behavior:

`=countifs(dataset_overview!$H12:H,C3)`  results in 445, which makes sense since I have 445 lines

`=countifs(dataset_overview!$H12:H,C3,dataset_overview!$J12:J,E3)` results in 401, which DOES NOT MAKE sense

in both cases, fields C3 and E3 = "*"
This means when I look at the cell all I see is this: *

Since this is the so-called "wildcard" (I assume .* in Regex-land) then why would the nested countif() result in less than 445?

When I apply the full list of columns the resulting output is decidedly less than 445. Yet the range is always `appropriate-column12:appropriate-column`

Suggestions sought!

Thanks

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I agree with player0. There are too many unknowns still. For instance, data type will matter. And honestly, for me at least, the goal is not clear after reading the post alone. Keep in mind that we "out here" can't see what you see and don't know what you know (e.g., data, ranges, data types, layout, end goal) unless you share that with us. So while a post may make perfect sense to the one writing it, for those of us without the benefit of seeing all the pieces, it's murky at best.

Answer (score 0):

Are there blank cells in your `dataset_overview!$J12:J`? It seems that when using `*` as criterion, it doesn't include the cells that have number of blank values and maybe that's your issue.

#### Blank:

[image: output]

#### Number:

[image: output2]

What is the actual behavior that you are expecting in the result? Maybe there's a better way to tackle it instead of using `countifs`.